# Strange Behaviour when Updating Cassandra row

Tags: cassandra, pyspark, cqlsh, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using `pyspark` and `pyspark-cassandra`.

I have noticed this behaviour on multiple versions of Cassandra(`3.0.x` and `3.6.x`) using `COPY`, `sstableloader`, and now `saveToCassandra` in `pyspark`.

I have the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int,
    time timestamp,
    a int,
    b int,
    c int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((id), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

and the following data

```
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 18, 18, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 0, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 19, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 22, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 0, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 23, 52, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 32,  2, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 32,  8, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 43, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 44, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 48, 49, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 49,  7, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 50,  5, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 50, 53, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 51, 53, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 51, 59, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 54, 35, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 55, 28, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 55, 55, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 56, 24, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 3, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 11, 14, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 11, 17, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 12,  8, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 12, 10, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 3, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 17, 43, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 17, 49, tzinfo=<UTC>), 0, 3, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 24, 12, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 24, 18, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 24, 18, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 2, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 24, 24, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2, 1, 0)
```

Towards the end of the data, there are two rows which have the same timestamp.

```
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 24, 18, tzinfo=<UTC>), 2, 1, 0)
(1, datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 1, 24, 18, tzinfo=<UTC>), 1, 2, 0)
```

It is my understanding that when I save to Cassandra, one of these will "win" - there will only be one row.

After writing to cassandra using

```
rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table, ['id', 'time', 'a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Neither row appears to have won. Rather, the rows seem to have "merged".

```
   1 |  2015-03-01 01:17:43+0000 |        1 |        2 |        0
   1 |  2015-03-01 01:17:49+0000 |        0 |        3 |        0
   1 |  2015-03-01 01:24:12+0000 |        1 |        2 |        0
   1 |  2015-03-01 01:24:18+0000 |        2 |        2 |        0
   1 |  2015-03-01 01:24:24+0000 |        2 |        1 |        0
```

Rather than the `2015-03-01 01:24:18+0000` containing `(1, 2, 0)` or `(2, 1, 0)`, it contains `(2, 2, 0)`.

What is happening here? I can't for the life of me figure out this behaviour is being caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little known effect that comes from the batching together of data. Batching writes assigns the same timestamp to all Inserts in the batch. Next, if two writes are done with the **exact** same timestamp then there is a special merge rule since there was no "last" write. The Spark Cassandra Connector uses intra-partition batches by default so this is very likely to happen if you have this kind of clobbering of values.

The behavior with two **identical** write timestamps is a merge based on the Greater value.

Given Table (key, a, b)

```
Batch
Insert "foo", 2, 1
Insert "foo", 1, 2
End batch
```

The batch gives both mutations the same timestamp. Cassandra cannot chose a "last-written" since they both happened at the same time, instead it just chooses the greater value of the two. The merged result will be

```
"foo", 2, 2
```

Comment: Thank you, I suspected something like this was happening, but couldn't find any information about it.

How, in practice, do people deal with this? Just making sure you have millisecond precise historical data?

Comment: Well there are a few things that you can do depending on your goal. 

Most of the time users just try to guarantee that there will not be duplicate Primary Keys in the same batch. If you wanted to maintain both records in C* you would need to differentiate them some how (like with milliseconds or TimeUUIDs)

Some users affix distinct timestamps to enforce an ordering (ie if every insert has an ascending order then they will be applied in that order.) You don't really have this option since your batches are built automagically. This also loses duplicates.